# diff in mod rewrite on apache 1.3 and 2.2

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache-1.3

What is the difference in mod_rewrite between Apache 1.3(.37) and 2.2(.11)?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^pages/edit(account|page)/([0-9]+)*$ ./index.php?p=edit$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w'-]+)*$ ./index.php?p=$1
```

I wrote this and it "works on my machine" which is running Apache 2.2.11 but the production server that it needs to run on is Apache 1.3.37. I am really new to mod rewrite and just started learning regex this morning. where do i go from here?

update: I installed Apache 1.3.37 on my local machine. I am getting the error "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration".

update 2: I fixed the problem i had with my local machine. now i am getting the same issue as on the production server.

Comment: Hi, what is exactly the problem you are having on the host running Apache 1 ? Any kind of error ? Or just "nothing happening" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache 1.*x* uses *POSIX Extended Regular Expressions* and those don’t understand shorthand character classes like `\w`. So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/edit(account|page)/([0-9]+)$ ./index.php?p=edit$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9_'-]+)$ ./index.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
[\w'-]
```

with this:

```
[-\w']
```

In some RegEx parsers, if you want `-` in a character set, it needs to be the first character, as it has a special meaning in character sets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Only the last rule was the problem. note the [^\w] instead of [\w'-].

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^\w]+)*$ ./index.php?p=$1
```

This works with Apache 1.3.37 but no longer functions in Apache 2.2.11. if anyone knows a way to get this to work in both I really want to understand this instead of just making it work.